# Search On Nested Field If Query Parameter Equal To True

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I need to search for a nested field like following:

```
    "bool": {
    "should": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "partnerData",
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "Dimmi",
                    "fields": ["partnerData.partnerName"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I need to do now is to make this filter optional from a query parameter.

If `online-booking: true` apply this filter, if `online-booking: false` do not apply the filter.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                "bool": {
                    "should": [{
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "partnerData",
                            "query": {
                                "query_string": {
                                    "query": "Dimmi",
                                    "fields": ["partnerData.partnerName"]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },{
                        "query_string": {
                            "query": "$negate-online-booking$",
                            "default_field": "name"
                        }
                    }]
                }
```

If `negate-online-booking` is different from `_exists_:name` filter will be applied. If its value is equal to `_exists_:name` filter will not applied.

If there is a better way to achieve the same result please suggest it.

Comment: "I can't, ES query is static." and now you modify query :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use multiple bool queries.
First query make sure that online-booking is false, second make sure that its true and second condition is also true. At least one query must match to be returned

```
{
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "term": {
                    "online-booking": false
                }
            },
            {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "online-booking": true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "nested": {
                                "path": "partnerData",
                                "query": {
                                    "query_string": {
                                        "query": "Dimmi",
                                        "fields": [
                                            "partnerData.partnerName"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: online-booking is not a field, it is a query parameter

Comment: @MarcoCalì Then why not to do it in the backend ? if its true add query if its false generate match_all

Comment: Because of the architecture I can't, ES query is static.

Comment: @MarcoCalì If es query is static then how you want to tell ES not to filter?

Comment: With a query parameter. I will post the solution shortly. Thanks anyway.